# how to find the posts page

Tags: posts

I had created the archive.php file and made it to show all posts, also have a sidebar that shows the time line, for example 2022, january 2022.
When I click on january 2022 I have a page showing me all posts from january 2022, and the url is https://mywebsite.com/2022/01
Now I want to know what is the url to get all the posts?
if I run this code I get the answer blog.

```php
if ( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) {
   echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) )).'">'.esc_html__( 'All posts', 'textdomain' ).'</a>';
} else {
   echo '<a href="'.esc_url( home_url( '/?posts=post' ) ).'">'.esc_html__( 'Blog', 'textdomain' ).'</a>';
}
```

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of Settings->Reading from admin side so I can see it.

Comment: added bellow.   :)

Comment: So I created a page called blog, then on reading settings had choose post page that blog page that I had created and that is it, is now the blogs page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is settings->reading,
I have a front-page.php that is why I didnt set the homepage displays

[image]

Comment: So I created a page and then here on the reading settings I had change to static page and choosen the page created for the post page dropdown.